# Prepared statement fails when i changed database

Tags: php, mysql, database

**the issue**

So I bumped into something curious this morning when I was updating my database. I executed a collation change in my database, changing it from `latin1` to `uft8`. However, my queries failed suddenly on my table. After some debugging, (rebuilding the table even with its original setup, but to no such avail) and receiving 500 internal errors, i realized it had to do with the `prepared statement`, so i tore it out, and replaced it  with a regular `mysqli_query`, and it surprisingly worked. So now I am wondering, was my prepared statement wrong the whole time, or did it fail because of a change in the database.

**the setup**

This is the current table set up. I changed it back to latin (and its innoDB) yet it didnt gave me the results back i wanted when i changed everything back to the original settings (which is how it is now)

[image: database setup]

**the code**

the original code was this and it worked fine until the change

```
    require_once '../db/dbControl.php';

    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET["id"]);  
    $sql = "SELECT  *
            FROM project
            WHERE   project.ProjectId = ? ";    
  $stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1,'i',$id);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt1,$ProjectId,$ProjectTitel,$ProjectOmschrijving, $ProjectOmschrijving,$ProjectDatum,$ProjectClient,$ProjectUrl);
  while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt1)){ 

  the code itself of the page

  }
```

So right now I am just using a regular `mysqli_query` in order to make it work

```
require_once '../db/dbControl.php';

id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET["id"]);   
$sql = "SELECT  *
        FROM project
        WHERE   project.ProjectId = '". $id ."'";   
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $ProjectId = $rows['ProjectId'];
    $ProjectTitel = $rows['ProjectTitel'];
    $ProjectExpertise = $rows['ProjectExpertise'];
    $ProjectOmschrijving = $rows['ProjectOmschrijving'];
    $ProjectDatum = $rows['ProjectDatum'];
    $ProjectClient = $rows['ProjectClient'];
    $ProjectUrl = $rows['ProjectUrl'];

    the code itself of the page

  }
```

I am a little bit confused (maybe i overlooked something here because to focussed on a little bit of code) but it only happens on the project table. I checked it against code that involves readouts, and they work all fine with prepped statements.

Hope anyone can spot what I couldn't

Comment: Read logs when you get 500 errors. No one can tell you what's wrong without knowing the error.

Comment: Try echoing `mysqli_error()` after the query fails.

Comment: This is a long shot, but I think this is the cause: mysqli prepares the statement and MySQL caches that statement and returns the handle to it. What happened next was that you recreated the table and MySQL **lost** the handle to it, which causes the whole thing to refer to no table. This is also why the regular query is working and statement isn't. Technically, you should reconnect in your code (check if you used persistent connection) and tell MySQL to drop the cache and re-prepare the statement after the table gets altered.

Comment: @N.B. I am going to try your suggestion. It makes sense in my oppinion. Is there documentation on how to clear the mysqli query cache?  Also, the 500 error, where is it logged? Cause i checked in the log file next to the index file, but there is no such thing written. Last error is on the 26th of november, is there another place where it logs 500 errors?

Comment: @Dorvalla - try using [mysqli_stmt_reset](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.reset.php) after altering the table. I'm not really sure what happens internally so I can't suggest anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I **wont** be able to tell you what happened but here are two thought's.

> The prepared statement execution consists of two stages: prepare and
>   execute. At the prepare stage a statement template is sent to the
>   database server. The server performs a syntax check and initializes
>   server internal resources for later use.
>
> A prepared statement can be executed repeatedly. Upon every execution
>   the current value of the bound variable is evaluated and sent to the
>   server. The statement is not parsed again. The statement template is
>   not transferred to the server again.

Maybe this is what happened, it could be that the prepared statements never reseted after you changed to utf8.

> Every prepared statement occupies server resources. Statements should be closed explicitly immediately after use. If not done explicitly, the statement will be closed when the statement handle is freed by PHP.
>
> Using a prepared statement is not always the most efficient way of
>   executing a statement. A prepared statement executed only once causes
>   more client-server round-trips than a non-prepared statement. This is
>   why the SELECT is not run as a prepared statement above.

Maybe the server memory (is/was) full?

Tekst from:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: I can tell you the memory wasn't full, since every other query worked, except the ones that involved this table and only on certain points. For example, the edit page where i can alter the variables in this table is not working either, however the page where i preload them to read out does. Its bizare.

Comment: Refer to N.B.'s comment.